# HTML Renderer for WPF not rendering correctly

Tags: c#, html, .net, wpf, xaml

I'm using "HTML Renderer for WPF" from NuGet. I'm finding the output to be inadequate, and the [discussion boards](https://htmlrenderer.codeplex.com/discussions) seem quiet and unmonitored so I thought it better to post here.

I have an HtmlPanel quite trivially in my xaml as

```
<htmlrenderer:HtmlPanel Grid.Row="2" 
                            Text="{Binding ReportContent}"/>
```

where

```
xmlns:htmlrenderer="clr-namespace:TheArtOfDev.HtmlRenderer.WPF;assembly=HtmlRenderer.WPF"
```

I'm feeding it some simple HTML;

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head><title>dummy</title></head>
<body>
<style>
table {
    border-spacing: 5px;
}
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
th, td {
    padding: 2px;
}
th {
    text-align: left;
}
</style>
<h1>Report for <b>Processing dev</b> generated 16/11/2015 16:02</h1>
<hr/>
<h2>Group <i>Everyone</i></h2> 
<table><caption>
<h3><b>Stage 1</b>
Run; Mass start</h3></caption><tr><th>pos</th><th>num</th><th>Name</th><th>Time</th></tr>
<tr><td>1</td><td>1</td><td>Person 1</td><td>00:41:00.0</td></tr>
<tr><td>2</td><td>2</td><td>Person 2</td><td>00:47:23.0</td></tr>
<tr><td>3</td><td>3</td><td>Person 3</td><td>00:47:24.0</td></tr>
<tr><td>4</td><td>4</td><td>Person 4</td><td>00:47:24.1</td></tr>
<tr><td>5</td><td>5</td><td>Person 5</td><td>00:52:00.0</td></tr>
<tr><td>6</td><td>6</td><td>Person 6</td><td>00:54:21.0</td></tr>
<tr><td>7</td><td>7</td><td>Person 7</td><td>00:54:32.0</td></tr>
<tr><td>8</td><td>8</td><td>Person 8</td><td>00:55:04.0</td></tr>
<tr><td>9</td><td>9</td><td>Person 9</td><td>00:56:23.0</td></tr>
<tr><td>10</td><td>10</td><td>Person 10</td><td>01:03:00.0</td></tr>
</table>
<table><caption>
<h3>Overall Results</h3>
</caption><tr><th>pos</th><th>num</th><th>Name</th><th>Time</th></tr>
<tr><td>1</td><td>1</td><td>Person 1</td><td>00:41:00.0</td></tr>
<tr><td>2</td><td>2</td><td>Person 2</td><td>00:47:23.0</td></tr>
<tr><td>3</td><td>3</td><td>Person 3</td><td>00:47:24.0</td></tr>
<tr><td>4</td><td>4</td><td>Person 4</td><td>00:47:24.1</td></tr>
<tr><td>5</td><td>5</td><td>Person 5</td><td>00:52:00.0</td></tr>
<tr><td>6</td><td>6</td><td>Person 6</td><td>00:54:21.0</td></tr>
<tr><td>7</td><td>7</td><td>Person 7</td><td>00:54:32.0</td></tr>
<tr><td>8</td><td>8</td><td>Person 8</td><td>00:55:04.0</td></tr>
<tr><td>9</td><td>9</td><td>Person 9</td><td>00:56:23.0</td></tr>
<tr><td>10</td><td>10</td><td>Person 10</td><td>01:03:00.0</td></tr>
</table>
</body></html>
```

My app renders this as follows. Note the absence of captions on the tables, the garbage upper left (which only appears when I have captions), and the lack of italic text ("Everyone" should be in italics). Loading this into Chrome renders correctly. I've checked it on `validator.w3.org` and the only error is the lack of a new "scoped" keyword in the style which isn't generally supported yet anyway.

[image]

Does anyone else have experience of this library? Given it doesn't seem to be functioning correctly in such a simple case, and seems like it may be dormant, is it worth persisting with? Is there a simple alternative that can just take a block of HTML and render it rather than what seems the over the top solution of CEFSharp, where various page providers have to be created and registered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `System.Windows.Controls.WebBrowser`:

```
<Grid>
    <WebBrowser x:Name="webBrowser1" Margin="0" Source="file:///C:/Users/Public/test01.html"/>
</Grid>
```

Or:

```
    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        webBrowser1.Source = new Uri("file:///C:/Users/Public/test01.html");
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Bindings cannot be set on WebBrowser components.